# Can you please provide - Google Bigquery dependency latest Dotnet NUGET package names, because the Bigquery example programs are not working

Tags: google-bigquery, google-api-dotnet-client

Need help to get 
Google Bigquery dependency latest Dotnet NUGET package names, because the Bigquery example programs are not working and it is giving the dependecy reference expections at IAuthorizationState

```
eError  1   The type 'DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.IAuthorizationState' exists in both 'c:\Echelon\GoogleDownloads\google-api-dotnet-client-1.8.1.source\Src\GoogleApis.Authentication.OAuth2.Tests\bin\Release\DotNetOpenAuth.dll' and 'c:\Users\Srinivasa\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BigQueryConsole1\packages\DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.Client.4.3.4.13329\lib\net40-full\DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.Client.dll'  c:\users\srinivasa\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BigQueryConsole1\BigQueryConsole1\Program.cs   37  24  BigQueryConsole1




  using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.DotNetOpenAuth;

using Google.Apis.Bigquery.v2;
using Google.Apis.Util;

namespace BigQueryConsole1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Register an authenticator.
            var provider = new NativeApplicationClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description);

            // Put your client id and secret here (from https://developers.google.com/console)
            // Use the installed app flow here.
            provider.ClientIdentifier = "asdfasd";
            provider.ClientSecret = "asdfasdf";

            // Initiate an OAuth 2.0 flow to get an access token
            var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator<NativeApplicationClient>(provider, GetAuthorization);

            // Create the service.
            var service = new BigqueryService(auth);

            // Do something with the BigQuery service here
            // Such as... service.[some BigQuery method].Fetch();
        }

        private static IAuthorizationState GetAuthorization(NativeApplicationClient arg)
        {
            // Get the auth URL:
            IAuthorizationState state = new AuthorizationState(new[] { BigqueryService.Scopes.Bigquery.GetStringValue() });
            state.Callback = new Uri(NativeApplicationClient.OutOfBandCallbackUrl);
            Uri authUri = arg.RequestUserAuthorization(state);

            // Request authorization from the user (by opening a browser window):
            Process.Start(authUri.ToString());
            Console.Write("  Authorization Code: ");
            string authCode = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine();

            // Retrieve the access token by using the authorization code:
            return arg.ProcessUserAuthorization(authCode, state);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an old version of the library.

The latest NuGet package is available in: http://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Bigquery.v2/

Take a look in our [samples repository](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse?repo=samples#hg) for samples on Google APIs (Unfortunately, we  don't have a sample for BigQuery)

You should also take a look in our [Getting Started guide](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/get_started) and to be more specific in the [OAuth 2.0 page](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth).

Good luck!

[UPDATE]
We improved the OAuth 2.0 library significantly. Take a look in our blog announcement from 
October 2013 - http://google-api-dotnet-client.blogspot.com/2013/10/announcing-release-of-160-beta-new.html.
In the OAuth 2.0 page I mentioned above there are the exact details of how to set your application to work with Google authorization. The library supports the OAuth 2.0 flows in Windows Phone, Windows 8 application and regular .NET 4.0 and higher.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply, but still I am getting the same error. even though I have used the mentioned NUGET packages...Can you please let me know what nugget packages need to use for 'using DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2;' && 'using Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.DotNetOpenAuth;'  and what is the reference for IAuthorizationState ?

Comment: Can you please help me to get the code for an big query example from C#.net.

Comment: Got the answers, now everything is working as expected, thank you :)